# How create a MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with some documents like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
    "className" : "model.MyClass",
    "createdOn" : ISODate("2018-10-23T11:00:00.000+01:00"),
    "status" : "A"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("2"),
    "className" : "model.MyClass",
    "createdOn" : ISODate("2018-10-23T11:01:00.000+01:00"),
    "status" : "B"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("3"),
    "className" : "model.MyClass",
    "createdOn" : ISODate("2018-10-23T11:02:00.000+01:00"),
    "status" : "C"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4"),
    "className" : "model.MyClass",
    "createdOn" : ISODate("2018-10-23T11:03:00.000+01:00"),
    "status" : "D"
}
```

Given a specific ID, how can I get the previous document that whose status not equals a specific status.

For example, I give the ID 4 and like to get the last document that status not is B neither C. So, I get the Object with Id 1.

How to create this query?

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

> db.yourcollection.find( {"status":{"$nin":["B","C"]}}
>   ).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1);

so use **not in** operator i.e. **$nin**,  then sort the data in descending order and limit the records to 1

see below documentations for details.

[$nin operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)

[mongo sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/)